# Enumerate Custom Slot Values from Speechlet

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is there any way to inspect or enumerate the Custom Slot **Values** that are set-up in your [interaction model](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference)? For Instance, Say you have an intent schema with the following intent:

```
{
  "intent": "MySuperCoolIntent",
  "slots":
  [
    {
      "name": "ShapesNSuch",
      "type": "LIST_OF_SHAPES"
    }
  ]
}
```

Furthermore, you've defined the LIST_OF_SHAPES Custom Slot to have the following Values:

```
SQUARE
TRIANGLE
CIRCLE
ICOSADECAHECKASPECKAHEDRON
ROUND
HUSKY
```

Question: is there a method I can call from my Speechlet or my RequestStreamHandler that will give me an enumeration of those Custom Slot Values??

I have looked through the Alexa Skills Kit's SDK Javadocs  [Located Here](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java/tree/master/javadoc/)

And I'm not finding anything.

I know I can get the Slot's value that is sent in with the intent:

```
String slotValue = incomingIntentRequest.getIntent().getSlot("LIST_OF_SHAPES").getValue();
```

I can even enumerate **ALL** the incoming Slots (and with it their values):

```
Map<String, Slot> slotMap = IncomingIntentRequest.getIntent().getSlots();
for(Map.Entry<String, Slot> entry : slotMap.entrySet())
{
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Slot slot = (Slot)entry.getValue();
    String slotName = slot.getName();
    String slotValue = slot.getValue();
    //do something nifty with the current slot info....
}
```

**What I would really like is something like:**

```
String myAppId = "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.<TheRestOfMyID>"; 

List<String> posibleSlotValues = SomeMagicAlexaAPI.getAllSlotValues(myAppId, "LIST_OF_SHAPES");
```

With this information I wouldn't have to maintain two separate "Lists" or "Enumerations"; One within the interaction Model and another one within my Request Handler. Seems like this should be a thing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the API does not allow you to do this.

However, since your interaction model is intimately tied with your development, I would suggest you check in the model with your source code in your source control system. If you are going to do that, you might as well put it with your source. Depending on your language, that also means you can probably read it during run-time.

Using this technique, you can gain access to your interaction model at run-time. Instead of doing it automatically through an API, you do it by best practice.

You can see several examples of this in action for Java in [TsaTsaTzu's examples](https://github.com/jjaquinta/EchoProofOfConcepts).

Comment: I like the pattern used in TsaTsaTzu's code. Basically, he caries a flat file with all the info's he needs to **Generate** the intent schema, sample utterances, and custom slot values. These generated files can then be uploaded to Amazon, AND can be read at runtime to enumerate possible slot values. I'm already tracking all these files, so reading them at run-time is NBD. I guess this workaround will have to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No - there is nothing in the API that allows you to do that.

You can see the full extent of the Request Body structure Alexa gives you to work with. It is very simple and available here:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#Request%20Format

Please note, the Request Body is not to be confused with the request, which is a structure in the request body, with two siblings: version and session.